# Private api with expressjs and react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So i am making a social media like site where i use react for frontend and expressjs for backend...

I was using public api till now but now i need private api to control some login info. So, i cannot understand how to do it. Because the link where it will request can be viewed by doing Ctrl+Shift+I and can be used by anyone

I still have methods to do but just wondering, if any way to know where does the request comming from

Let assume that the api site is `api.some.site` and the main site is `some.site`, so the request should only come from some.site else send 404 response and i need to do it with expressjs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to do it but I wanted to give you some information to think about. If you want people to be able to log in, on your site. That api end point has to be unprotected, because a logged out person does not have any credentials yet. When logged in the user would be able to access protected end points right? End points like password change of viewing specific pages. So all the data an user should or should not have access to should be handled by the server. You website is only a mechanism to make your data look pretty and easy to handle. So in a way you shouldn't care about people using your open end points from another location because their open anyways.

Authentication should never be handled client side. It should always be handled by a server.

This is my opinion, hope it helps. Sorry if it's not what you are looking for